# SPSS - Create dummy for top volume months within customer grouping

Tags: date, grouping, spss, dummy-variable

I need to create a dummy for the top purchase months within each customer ID. That is, if a month belong to one of the four months within the year where the customer purchased the most then it is noted with the number 1, otherwise 0.

Example of data, cust id, order date, volume and new variable dummy:
[image]

This code creates some sample data:

```
data list free/ID volume (2f4).
begin data 
1 100 1 500  2 1 2 2 2 3 2 90 1 600 1 90 1 870 2 9 2 8 2 10
end data.
```

Comment: Don't provide information as image which can be text.

Answer (score 0):

Using the sample data in the question, this code will create a new variable containing the dummy according to your definition:

```
RANK VARIABLES=volume (A) BY ID /RANK.
compute high4=(Rvolume<=4).
```